# Limit message sending logic

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am looking for some tips as to how I could properly limit sending messages per second. I have an ajax request that sends data to a PHP file for processing when a user presses a button. I would like to limit the amount of times a user can press the submit button in a second to a certain amount. This would effectively allow for not more than 3 messages per second. Not quite sure how I would be able to get this done, any suggestions?

Comment: Store the last time a user submitted a comment on your server, and reject following requests if it was not long enough ago.

Comment: I was thinking of this method too, but wondered if the extra server side check would be a big overhead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to limit the amount of times a user can press the submit button in a second to a certain amount

That's easy, disable it while a request is active and enable it after a certain time has passed. However you need to notice that "click on the button" is not the same as "request sent to the server", you need a serverside logic as well.

```
$('#theButton').click(function() {
    var button = this,
        ratelimit = true,
        ajaxrunning = true;
    button.disabled = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        ratelimit = false;
        if (!ajaxrunning)
            button.disabled = false;
    }, 5000);
    $.ajax(…).always(function() {
        ajaxrunning = false;
        if (!timeout)
            button.disabled = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: True I should have been more specific about the "click on button" vs "server request" which I really would want to prevent the server request and client side alerting of the timeout.

Comment: After sending two requests, you get a 5 second cool down time before being able to send again

Comment: As for server side, maybe I could just do a simple if((now - lastTime) < 5seconds) block message

Answer (score 0):

You could simply set a timer on the button click event which initially disables the button then re-enables it after a certain time.

```
$('.myButton').click(function() {
    ...
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
    }, 2000);
})
```

Comment: A rate limit needs to be implemented serverside, else it's useless.

Comment: You should not use the `disabled` attribute, but the property.

Comment: Of course, this is simply a JavaScript-enabled client-sided solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the button after click, then use `setTimeout()` to re-enable it after some time:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#myButton').removeAttr('disabled');
    }, 1000);
}
```